# Determine if a CKEDITOR instance is inside a particular DOM container

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I use the following loop to bind an action to the focus event on every CKEDITOR instance:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('focus', function() {
        my_custom_function(this.name);
    });
}
```

I want to change this so that it only runs on CKEDITOR instances that occur inside of a particular DOM element. For example, using jquery notation, the DOM element might be:

```
$("#container")
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the contents of CKEDITOR.instances, you may actually do all of this with just one clean jQuery statement.  How are you populating CKEDITOR.instances?

Answer (score 1):

Each instance has a property that holds the main node where CKEditor is created, so you could use something like

```
var testContainer = $("#container");

for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[i];
    if ( jQuery.contains( testContainer, instance.container.$ ) )
    {
    instance.on('focus', function() {
        my_custom_function(this.name);
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it's throwing an error in jquery.js:  a.compareDocumentPosition is not a function

Comment: I wrote it on the fly, but you should be able to find out what's the problem with Firebug or any other javascript debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten AlfonsoML's code to make it work for one of my projects.

Please note that the first argument of `jQuery.contains()` must be a DOM element (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

Here is my code:

```
// Retrieving container DOM object
var domContainer = $("#container")[0];

// Iterating CKEDITOR instances
for (var intanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {

    // Testing if instance is inside container
    if ( $.contains(domContainer, CKEDITOR.instances[intanceName].container.$ ) ) {

        // Binding with focus event
        CKEDITOR.instances[intanceName].on('focus', function() {

            // Executing custom function with instance name as an argument
            my_custom_function(intanceName);
        });
    }
}
```